# How do I host a REST API in Amazon?

Tags: java, rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I’m using Amazon RDS (MySQL) for DB and it is connected to mobile app via REST API we have. I know creating EC2 and hosting it, is there a better and easy way to host this REST API? FYI, REST is developed in Java 8. The output of it is a `.war` file, so we have to deploy it.

I am asking this because now lot are moving to PaaS systems and they do lot of work we should be doing in server configurations and security.

Comment: What about using Spring Boot?

Answer (score 2):

Elastic Beanstalk, can do all that you want. You can do a single instance if you want or you can put it behind a Load Balancer.

Give this [Getting Started Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-getstarted.html) a run.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Amazon API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) is the solution you are looking for . There you can define the rest-interface with GET/POST etc., connect your Mysql RDS instance and connect this to a [Lambda stream](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc-rds.html).

[image]

I am working on a similar setup with a DynamoDB-instance.

Comment: I looked into this. It seems like we have to write code inside the console they provide, not to upload our REST API, which is a `.war` file

Comment: How about Elastic Beanstalk? That accepts a war-file. I try to remain within a free tier so I have only created a default example which I deleted again.

Comment: Me too. I am also trying to remain in the same. `Elastic Beanstalk` seems OK, can we get static IP? I will also need access protection, possible implementation of SSL

Comment: You can use CloudFront to create a TLS-certficate and act as CDN. Add a CNAME with your DNS-provider that point to the unique name Amazon assigns. I wrote a guide https://gnome.no/2016/06/amazon-cloudfront-with-custom-certificate/ on how to obtain a certificate. Maybe it is useful?

Comment: I tried to import data into dynamodb using datapipelines and AWS created m3-instances on EC2 which are quite expensive. So if you create a elastic beanstalk service be sure to check what servers it creates. I read a blog about datapipelines and found out I had four instances created by AWS.